# Objective C Validation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've been watching [WWDC 2014 Advanced iOS Application Architecture and Patterns](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#229) and found it interesting and suited for my case. Specially the validation part. In my example app I've to check if a team are build up a certain way. Checks could be:

- more than 4 players
- two female, two male
- etc

So I've created this so far:

```
@protocol DEXValidator <NSObject>
@required
- ( BOOL ) validate:(NSError * __autoreleasing *)error;
@end

//Implements procotol DEXValidator
@implementation DEXValidatorHasFourPlayers

- ( BOOL ) validate:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error {
    if( _team.length != 4 )
        *error = ....

    return _team.length == 4  
}

@end
```

So far I can see how this works, but now came the part I didn't understand. He talks about composition and creates and overall validator for all the checks like this:

```
//Implements procotol DEXValidator
@implementation DEXValidatorTeam
- ( instancetype ) init {
    ...
    _hasfourplayers = [DEXValidatorHasFourPlayers new];
    ...morechecks...
    ...
}


- ( BOOL ) validate:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error {
    ... 
}
```

But my question now is how can I return all the NSErrors to the caller. So I can display a list what is wrong with the team. Since in the video he changes the display of all the form elements.  Or should the overall not implement the validator protocol and do something else?

Comment: Make a global class that have a mutableArray property, then store all your error there.

Answer (score 0):

You could use block syntax:

```
- (void)validateWithCompletionBlock:(void(^)(BOOL success, NSArray *errors))completionBlock {

    NSMutableArray *errors = [NSMutableArray new];

    if (_team.length != 4){
        [errors addObject:[NSError errorWithDomain:@"123" code:123 userInfo:nil]];
    }

    // perform more checks adding NSErrors to Array       

    if (completionBlock) {
        completionBlock(errors.count == 0, errors.count > 0 ? errors : nil);
    }
}
```

the check would look something like this:

```
[self validateWithCompletionBlock:^(BOOL success, NSArray *errors) {
        if (!success) {
            // Loop through errors array ....
        } else {
            // Continue ....
        }
    }];
```

Comment: What you have right now is something I want to avoid. This method will be much longer with the amount of checks grows. That is why I like the way which is displayed in the video. 

It separates the several rules in classes and this gives me a couple advantages.

Comment: I'd change `completionBlock(errors.count == 0, errors);` to `completionBlock(errors.count == 0, errors.count > 0 ? errors : nil);`. Otherwise somebody might check if the errors array is `nil` and would always get that it exists.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt see this video yet, so I might have misunderstood your question. Anyway, wouldn't it be possible for you to use a pattern where you return a pointer to a `NSArray` containing the `NSError`s, and not to just to a single `NSError`? Something like this:

```
- (BOOL)validate:(NSArray *__autoreleasing *)errors {
    NSMutableArray *tempErrors = [NSMutableArray new];

    if (team.length != 4) {
        [tempErrors addObject:[NSError errorWithDomain:@"123" code:123 userInfo:nil]];
    }

    if (!team.isGenderEqual) {
        [tempErrors addObject:[NSError errorWithDomain:@"456" code:456 userInfo:nil]];
    }

    if (tempErrors.count > 0) {
        *errors = [NSArray arrayWithArray:tempErrors];
    }

    return tempErrors.count == 0;
}
```

You could call this by:

```
NSArray *errors;

BOOL success = [self validate:&errors];

for (NSError *error in errors) {
    NSLog(@"error %@", error);
}
```